# Xorg drivers, Mesa drivers and Kernel drivers, how this relationship?

Tags: linux, xorg

I have this email >>

> > Hi foks, I have compiled Mesa Cell driver, and it is great!
> >     can I use this, rather than ps3fb for video driver?
> >     thanks so much
> >     and sorry my bad english.

answer
>

> No.  The ps3fb driver and Mesa Cell driver are totally different things.
>
> -Brian

another question.

> Hi, thanks for you answer
>   how can I understand this?
>   ps3fb driver and Mesa Cell driver are totally different things,
>   there are some documents to explain this?,
>   I want to understand Mesa3D, and your relation with Xorg, and Kernel drivers..

answer:

> Sorry but I do not have time to explain everything.
>
> The Mesa Cell driver implements OpenGL for 3D graphics.
>
> The ps3fb driver is a low-level driver for simply displaying the framebuffer.
>
> If you use google, you can probably find more information.
>
> -Brian

I can't found this information in google, someone can help me?
I want to work on linux, and write drivers.
thanks so much.

Comment: [this link](http://stefon.wordpress.com/2006/12/22/description-of-how-opengl-on-linux-works/) may have the information you want about Mesa, X.org, ... What kind of driver do you want to write ?

Answer (score 0):

Mesa implements 3D using OpenGL. Some Mesa drivers are accelerated, some aren't.
X.Org drivers implement 2D, TV-out, multi-monitor support etc.
Both of them use the kernel.
edit: To clarify: Mesa and X.org drivers aren't replaceable, they are both used when needed.

Comment: some more information? Thanks for your answer, but it is a bit vague.